# Trackbars and cv2.namedWindow() in google Colab

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, image-processing, google-colaboratory

is there a way to create trackbars in Google Colab? On a code running locally one would simply do something like this:

```
cv2.namedWindow("Trackbars") 
cv2.createTrackbar("L - S", "Trackbars", 0, 255, nothing)
while: ...

   ls = cv2.getTrackbarPos("L - S", "Trackbars")
```

I would like to do the same in Colab. Are there any workarounds, any patches?

Answer (score 0):

no there isnt, you cannot use opencv's gui functions on colab

however, there is a `cv2_imshow()` [mock replacement](https://colab.research.google.com/#snippetFileIds=%2Fv2%2Fexternal%2Fnotebooks%2Fsnippets%2Fadvanced_outputs.ipynb&snippetQuery=Showing%20CV2%20Images), to show an image

Answer (score 0):

There is restriction from colab you can not use window function of cv2 because its use for local system as well as you can't use camera direct.
you can use cv2_imshow("img", img) function for image show.